# Editing certain line of a file in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write a script to automatically create the files and configuration for an apache server website quickly, as it usually takes me around 5 minutes and is very boring.

The part I'm struggling with is this line...

```
# TODO: edit ServerName and DocumentRoot to use $1 and /var/www/$1/public
```

Here is the full script

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/$1
sudo mkdir /var/www/$1/public
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/$1
sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www/$1
sudo usermod -aG www-data $USER
echo "<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>" > /var/www/$1/public/index.php
cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/$1.io.conf
# TODO: edit ServerName and DocumentRoot to use $1 and /var/www/$1/public
cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/$1.io.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/$1.io.conf
sudo -- sh -c "echo $1.io   127.0.0.1 >> /etc/hosts"
sudo service apache2 restart
xdg-open $1.io
sleep 5
code /var/www/$1
```

How would I replace certain parts of a .conf apache file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your settings have the below format :

```
ServerName your.server.name
DocumentRoot '/some/path'
```

You could do something like below (with `GNU sed`) :

```
cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf "/tmp/${1}.io.conf"
sed -Ei "s|^([[:blank:]]*)#?([[:blank:]]*ServerName).*$|\1\2 ${1}|;
        s|^([[:blank:]]*)#?([[:blank:]]*DocumentRoot).*$|\1\2 '/var/www/${1}/public'|;" "/tmp/${1}.io.conf"
mv "/tmp/${1}.io.conf" /etc/apache2/sites-available/
```

Comment: Thanks, but this throws the following error: `sed: -e expression #1, char 44: unknown option to `s'
gio: file:///var/www/sitename.io: Error when getting information for file “/var/www/sitename.io”: No such file or directory`

Comment: @AshKetchum That is weird. The  `no such file` error should be consequence of `sed` failing ! Just to confirm, do you have `GNU sed`  installed? For instance what does `sed --version`  return?

Comment: It returns `sed (GNU sed) 4.7`, I'm guessing yes I have it installed.

Comment: @AshKetchum I couldn't reproduce the error here. It is working as intended with a test file here.

Comment: Here's an update error: `sed: couldn't open temporary file /etc/apache2/sites-available/sed0Eibi1: Permission denied`

Comment: @AshKetchum Ah ! There  you're. :) The `-i` option with `sed` does an inplace editing of your config file which requires  root permissions.  Append  a `sudo` before the `sed`?

Comment: `sudo` is there before the command, I tried with just -E and not `-Ei` but it just prints out the new content.

Comment: @AshKetchum You should use the `-i` option. Please see my edit.

Comment: Your code is now half working, the ServerName replacement doesn't seem to work, it doesn't seem to remove the # in front of ServerName, if you can fix that I can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. The two I use most are:

1. `patch`

*An example of patching an Ubuntu flavored Apache conf file*

```
patch -d/ -p0 <<'EOF'
--- /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
+++ /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
@@ -54,6 +54,7 @@

 # Global configuration
 #
+ServerName your_hostname_goes_here

 #
 # ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
EOF
```

2. `perl -pi -e 's%old_string%new_string%' filename`